# TYPO3 JavaScript error in template editor

Tags: javascript, typo3, typo3-9.x

With the following typoscript code I'm getting a javascript error in `Typo3 9.5.1`:

```
page.headerData.20 = TEXT
page.headerData.20.value (
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxx', 'xxxx');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
)
```

> TypeError: cc[(cc.length - 1)] is null[Weitere Informationen]
>   typoscript.js:1194:18

Whats the error?

Comment: The google analytics JS code is not related to the error you posted. There is no variable with the name "cc" in the code above.

Comment: By the way: "typoscript.js" is this file name some kind of funny naming? (Just asking because typoscript has nothing to do with javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the code is only related in that way you can reproduce the error in TYPO3. "typoscript.js" is a file in TYPO3 loaded in the backend.

Comment: Please add more information on your setup. What frontend URL are you calling. What's the source in the browser like? Where is typoscript.js loaded in frontend? Which extensions are loaded?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information: I'm in the backend and calling the template editor.

Comment: I'm currently totally unsure why and how your TypoScript like that is loaded in the Template module in the backend...
(I'm aware that some TS is parsed in the BE for Extbase, but that does not involve anything with the PAGE content object.)

Comment: May I suggest to get in touch with us on the Slack support channels with this topic, so we can figure that one out?
https://my.typo3.org/index.php?id=35

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same Problem.